# Feedburner does not get links right

Tags: feedburner

Feedburner doesn't get my feed links right. I tried resyncing and pinging and everything at my disposal but it doesn't seem to work. Then I emailed my problem to feedburner-feedback@google.com and I got no response. I just can't stand to see my feed getting wrong links.
e.g: http://www.codingtales.com/post/getting-started-with-mvvm is the link in the actual feed (http://www.codingtales.com/rss) while feedburner links go to http://www.codingtales.com/getting-started-with-mvvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need Feedburner to link to the correct post, change your `<guid>` tag to one that matches what you already have in the `<link>` tag.

```
<link>http://www.example.com/post/bacon</link>
<guid isPermalink="true">http://www.example.com/post/bacon</guid>
```

That should make Feedburner have its rewriting of links back to your blog point to the correct location.

Or you can have it the other way:

```
<link>http://www.example.com/post/bacon</link>
<guid isPermalink="false">bacon</guid>
```

Where you tell Feedburner to not use the GUID tag as a permalink.

You may be using statistics tracking for clickthroughs and why the rewriting of the links is happening in the first place.

> #### [Why don't my feed content item links work?](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79014)
>
> By adding the `isPermaLink` attribute to your original feed's XML template as shown, FeedBurner will know to look in the  element for the URL to rewrite and ignore the `<guid>`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. But can you explain me why it looks for the GUID rather than the link?

Comment: Researched the why of what's happening. Might want to reword your question as if this is the selected answer, you aren't looking for a Feedburner alternative and instead why your links are borked. @cod

Comment: You can additionally deactivate the tracking function in feedburner temporarily until you fix this.